# How to count occurrences of specified value in column in Pandas using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe where I need to count how many rows contain 'False' in column IsCleared.

```
       IsCleared
0       False   
1       False
2       True
3       False
```

So I do the following in Python 2.7:

```
sum = df[df.IsCleared == 'False'].count()
print sum
```

But I get this error:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = getattr(x, name)(y)
invalid type comparison
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(~df.IsCleared).sum()`

Comment: I think your data type for `IsCleared` is boolean, but you are making a comparison to a string. These are different types so they cannot be compared.

Comment: `df[~df['IsCleared']].shape[0]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That's a great solution. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @JoeT.Boka Yes, actually. Posted :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes! And I up-voted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a boolean mask. So why not work with it?

```
>>> (~df.IsCleared).sum()
3
```

Negate `False` values to `True`, and then sum them up (since `True` is equivalent to `1`, and `False` equivalent to `0`, this works nicely).

Comment: Very neat. Thank you! What does ~ mean before df.IsCleared?

Comment: @sprogissd It just means that I negate the mask, so all F values become T, and vice versa. Lets me count the number F values that way once I negate them.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
df['IsCleared'].value_counts()
```

This should give you the total counts of false and true

Comment: The OP asked how to count the `False` values, not both `False` and `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You did it wrong because you turned `False` into a string `'False'` at the line

`df[df.IsCleared == 'False'].count()`.

Thus, it is complaining because you make it compare a boolean value with a string.

> invalid type comparison

Change it into

```
df[df.IsCleared == False].count()
```

and it shall work.